# Showing multiple values in DropDownList and accesing those values programatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox

I have DropDownList this looks something like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="lds1"
                                 DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="Description" Height="22px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                Width="339px" ondatabound="ddl1_DataBound">                                    
</asp:DropDownList>
```

LinqDataSource

```
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="lds1" runat="server" ContextTypeName="MyDataContext"
                                TableName="MyView" > 

</asp:LinqDataSource>
```

MyView:

```
SELECT     Description, COUNT(*) AS Quantity
FROM         MyTable
GROUP BY Description
```

In dropdownlist I want to show data like this:

description1 32

where description1 is string from MyView.Description and 32 is integer from MyView.Quantity. And I need to be able to access quantity of selected dropdown item programaticaly.

I grouping of data can also be done directly in LinqDataSource. Whatever works.

Answer (score 1):

Use the ListControl.AppendDataBoundItems Property:

[AppendDataBoundItems Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.appenddatabounditems.aspx)

From the documentation: "The AppendDataBoundItems property allows you to add items to the ListControl object before data binding occurs. After data binding, the items collection contains both the items from the data source and the previously added items."

Use the [SelectedValue property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue.aspx) to programmatically access the quantity.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried concatenating the results at SQL level, assigning the result to a variable of your own and using this in the dropdown list?

My SQL needs to polishing, but if I remember right it is something like this:

```
SELECT field1 + ' -' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, field2) as DisplayValue
```

You would then display DisplayValue in the dropdown box.